# How to drop rows where one column is an array of NaN in pandas data frame

Tags: pandas, nan, numpy-ndarray

I have the following array *t* from which I make a data frame

```
t = array([[1, array(nan)],
       [1, array(nan)],
       [1, array(nan)],
       [1, array(nan)],
       [2, array([4, 5, 6])]], dtype=object)

df = pd.DataFrame(t, names=['a','b'])

    a   b
0   1   nan
1   1   nan
2   1   nan
3   1   nan
4   2   [4, 5, 6]
```

I want to drop all nan rows and have something like this:

```
    a   b
4   2   [4, 5, 6]
```

df.dropna() does not work when the nans are inside an array.
Neither does df[~df.b.isnull()]

Comment: Is possible in last row is `[nan,4,5]` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use subtract `np.nan` (or any math operations) before to reduce the dimension:

```
out = df[pd.notna(df['b'] - np.nan)]
print(out)

# Output
   a          b
4  2  [4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension to perform [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = df[[not np.isnan(x).any() for x in df['b']]]
```

*NB. if you want to only remove a row if **all** values are NaN, then use `np.isnan(x).all()` in place of `np.isnan(x).any()`.*

Output:

```
   a          b
4  2  [4, 5, 6]
```

Intermediate:

```
[not np.isnan(x).any() for x in df['b']]
# [False, False, False, False, True]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select first value of array:

```
out = df[df.b.str[0].notna()]
print (out)
   a          b
4  2  [4, 5, 6]
```

If need remove rows with at least one `NaN` per row:

```
out = df[df.b.explode().astype(float).notna().groupby(level=0).all()]
print (out)
   a          b
4  2  [4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
df.applymap(lambda x: x).dropna()
```

Output:

```
   a          b
4  2  [4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Interesting side-effect, although maybe too cryptic to be used in real life ;)

Comment: Thanks for having commented my solution, @mozway! You are absolutely right: That is too cryptic! Since I do not know a lot of Python, sometimes I end up into mysterious solutions like this! :-)